# C: pointers to arrays, and destructive sorting

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, bubble-sort

I wrote a brief piece of code. It has two functions: bubbleSort is a bubble sorting function (smallest to largest), and "int main" is used to test this piece of code with an int array of size 5.

I'd like this to destructively sort the array, and not simply pass through a copy. I have looked and looked, but I am still not entirely clear how this should work. What am I missing here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bubbleSort(int values[], int n);

int main(void) {
//set simple test array to make sure bubbleSort works
    int arr[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};
//run it through function, and then print the now sorted array to make sure
    bubbleSort(arr, 5);
    printf("%i", arr);
    return 0;
}


void bubbleSort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0, hold = 0; j < n-i; j++) {
            if (values[j] > values[j+1]) {
                hold = values[j+1];
                values[j+1] = values[j];
                values[j] = hold;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Note: The rest of my code looks sound to my amateur coding mind, but please give me pointers on what i can improve, what can be better, etc. I thought about using recursion for the bubble sort but i'm not yet as comfortable with C as I'd like to be to implement that. However if you have suggestions i'll be more than happy to read them.

thanks!

Comment: "In-place sorting" would be a better name...

Comment: `printf("%i", arr);` is wrong, you must print an element of the array i.e. `arr[0]`, not the array itself.

Comment: The `n-i` is ok, but the first loop should start at `i = 1`. If `i` is 0, then the inner loop is `for (j=0;j<n;j++)`. And when `j==n-1`, then `values[j+1]` is not a valid entry in the array.

Comment: Or [just do something like this](http://pastebin.com/BdSU8ApA) and eliminate one of the index variables entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your function is sorting the array (although with some bugs) and you are just printing the result incorrectly. printf doesn't know how to print arrays. Instead, you need to use a loop to print each integer one at a time:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
  printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

After changing this, the output is `1 2 3 4 5`, as expected.

However, as mentioned in the comments, there are some bugs in the implementation of the bubblesort. For example, it tries to read elements from indedex after the end of the array, which is undefined behavior (namely, `j+1` can be `5`, which is out of bounds). I would recommend checking your book again to get a correct implementation of bubblesort.

Comment: You got lucky that the value after the end of the array was bigger than 5. Try `int arr[] = {5,4,3,2,1,0};` while leaving the rest of the code the same.

Comment: The 5 I used is the number of elements in the array. You would obviously need to use 6 if the array had 6 elements. Ideally you would store the number of elements in a variable or `#define` to avoid repeating the number of elements all over the place.

Comment: The point is that the sort routine has undefined behavior, it accesses beyond the end of the array. By making the array bigger, and not telling the sort routine that the array is bigger, you can control the value that's beyond the end of the array, and prove that the sort is broken.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that is the case. If @ozymandias1 is reading this, I would recommend checking your book (or even wikipedia) again to implement a correct bublesort algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue in you bubble sort code which **must** be fixed. Your inner loop has the issue:

```
/* for (int j = 0, hold = 0; j < n-i; j++) { */  // ISSUE here
for (int j = 0, hold = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) { // j < n-i-1 should be the condition
```

This is becasue, take the case of when `i = 0`, i.e. the first iterartion of outer for loop.  This time, `j < n - i` will be true when `j` is one less than `n` - which is the last index of your array. Then you do comaprision between `values[j]` and `values[j+1]`, where `values[j+1]` is clearly out of bound of your array. This will invoke `undefined behavior`, and your function will not give deterministic results.

Next improvement could be that your outer loop only needs to iterate from `i = 0 till i < n-1`, i.e. one times less than the total elements. You are interating one time more than needed.

Third, you can use a flag to keep track of weather you `swap` at least once in your inner loop. If there there are no swaps in inner loop then it means that array is already sorted. So at the end of each iteration of inner loop you can see if any swap was done, and if no swaps were done then break out of the outer loop. This will improve performance in cases where array is already almost sorted.

```
void bubbleSort(int values[], int n)
{        
    int swap;   // To use as a flag

    // for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {                 
            swap = 0;     // set swap flag to zero
            // for (int j = 0, hold = 0; j < n-i; j++) {
            for (int j = 0, hold = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
                    if (values[j] > values[j+1]) {
                            hold = values[j+1];
                            values[j+1] = values[j];
                            values[j] = hold;
                            swap = 1;        // swap was done
                    }
            }
            if (swap == 0)   // If no swap was done
                    break;   // Means array already sorted
    }
    return;
}
```

And, although not related to your sorting function, as others have pointed out, `printf("%i", arr);` is wrong, and will invoke `undefined behavior` because you are using a wrong format specifier in `printf`. It seems like you are trying to print the array. For that you can do:

```
// printf("%i", arr);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i];)
printf("\n");
```

Comment: sps, thank you so much for taking the time to write out this detailed and thorough response. really appreciate your help and kindness.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already sorts the array in-place - although there is a bug in it. I'll address the subject of the question only (in-place sorting of an array in C) as comments have already highlighted the bugs with the sort function.

The print-out of the result is incorrect though as it tries to print the `arr` pointer as an integer:

```
sort.c:10:18: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("%i", arr);
            ~~   ^~~
1 warning generated.
```

However changing this to:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%i", arr[i]);
```

fixes the problem with the output.

Perhaps your confusion comes from how arrays are actually a syntactic way to access pointers in C. `arr` is a pointer. `arr[1]` is the same as `*(arr + 1)` (the contents of the pointer `arr + 1` using pointer arithmetic, which increments the pointer by the `sizeof` the type). So when you pass `arr` into the function, you are passing a pointer to the existing array, then you are modifying its contents, sorting the array in-place.

Comment: thank you! did not know that arr is a pointer, appreciate all the help.